# Java version that RIM used

Tags: java, blackberry

Does anyone know what version of Java that RIM modified JVM used ?I found an article that says that RIM modify the default JVM, for the blackberry device. what version of Java?
Blackberry OS 4.x, 5.0, 6.0, it's all of BB OS using the same version of Java, or upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's 1.4 (no generics, unfortunately).

Comment: Can I use Jvm version 1.5 in Blackberry device ?

Comment: In the [BlackBerry docs for the JDE Component Package](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1072/BlackBerry%20Java%20Development%20Environment%20Component%20Package%20Release%20Notes%20-%20build%20version.pdf) it says, "To use the BlackBerry® Java® Development Environment Component Package with the Eclipse development environment, you must set Eclipse to use a Java compiler compliance level of 1.4."

Answer (score 2):

It's Java-ME.  Language wise, that means it is Java 1.3 - there is no 'assert' keyword, which was introduced in Java 1.4

Comment: You're right about the lack of `assert`. However, RIM says in [their docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1072/BlackBerry%20Java%20Development%20Environment%20Component%20Package%20Release%20Notes%20-%20build%20version.pdf) to set the Java compiler compliance level to 1.4 (not 1.3) when using the Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: Those are some rather old docs - BlackBerry 4.3 hasn't been current for over four years, and the copyright notice is for 2006.  It really is Java 1.3.   You need class compatibility for Java 1.1, and that's not possible when your Java language compliance is set to 1.4 in Eclipse.

Comment: I have always set Eclipse to use 1.4 for my BB projects and never have had a problem. What do you mean that it's not possible? Also, do you really think RIM decided to move _backward_ in their level of Java compatibility since 2006?